# How long before first marathon?

Tags: marathon, beginners, half-marathon

For someone of a healthy weight and in good cardiovascular shape (swimming and cycling) how long should I wait before my first marathon? Until last month I never ran more than 5 miles in my life, but I now run 15k+ about once a week.

I would like to run a marathon in about 5 months. I've found a 16 week plan that seems reasonable to me. Would that be too soon since I have been only running for 1 month? Based on my run last weekend (16k) I am guessing I could complete a half marathon in under two hours today.

Comment: We can't tell you how your body's going to react to the training you put it through. More so because we don't know what condition your body is in right now, and we don't know what type of training you plan on doing, and we don't know what you plan on eating. You're just gonna have to try it and find out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would rather say it is not about waiting if not about preparation and training. I've seen people starting from the zero(in terms of running, otherwise in a good fitness) with 16 weeks plans and successfully completing their first marathons, so i would say the 5 months you have ahead of you should be enough. however don't go crazy and set some realistic goals, if you think you are able to run half marathon in less than 2 hours, then the 4 hour mark should be good starting target, so make sure the plan you have found is appropriate, that being said try to stick to the plan, dont push it too hard, dont underestimate the importance of the rest days, pay attention to the nutrition and hydration (not just before during and after a running session), you can practice these in the long runs